# Table splitting

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-table

Here is my code to display table:

```
<table id="ws_table" class="ws_table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-light">
            <th>WS Code</th>
            <th>WS Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="reportWs_table">
        <?php
            if (is_array($workschedules)) {
                //$i=0;
                foreach ($workschedules as $workschedulesingle) {
                    $cnt++;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="">
                            <?php echo $workschedulesingle['workScheduleCode']; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="">
                            <?php echo $workschedulesingle['workScheduleName']; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
            }
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is its a long table. So I want to split into two. How can I split the table vertically? i.e. When the entries exceeds 20 it will goes to next table. How can I create it?

Comment: Don't you like to try out pagination instead of splitting the table?

Answer (score 2):

• Set `Index` `$i=0`
• Loop every `row`
• Check if the `index` start on 0
• Check if `Index` reach 20/limit 
• If reach 20/limit reset `Index` to 0 again.

```
<?php
//INIT INDEX $i
$i = 0;
if(is_array($workschedules)){
   // FOR EACH ROW
  foreach($workschedules as $workschedulesingle){
     //EVERY TIME THE INDEX START PRINT THE TABLE
    if($i==0){
      ?>
      <table id="ws_table" class="ws_table">
        <thead>
          <tr class="bg-light">
            <th>WS Code</th>
            <th>WS Name</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="reportWs_table">
        <?php } ?>
        <tr>
          <td class=""><?php echo $workschedulesingle['workScheduleCode'];?></td>
          <td class=""><?php echo $workschedulesingle['workScheduleName'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
         //IF THE INDEX REACH 20/LIMIT, PRINT CLOSING TABLE TAGS
         if($i==20){ ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <?php
    }
    //IF THE INDEX EXCEED 20/LIMIT, RESET $i TO 0 AND START AGAIN
    $i++;
    if($i>20){
      $i=0;
    }
  }
}else{

} 
?>
```